# Is this a valid sentence?

Tags: translation

Here's the sentence:

[image: "susana"]

Hmmm, all I could get was "Susana"?

But I don't really understand why quoting "ス" makes sense.

Is this a valid sentence?

Comment: It's not a sentence. It's a person's name presumably.

Answer (score 5):

Those aren't quotes; they're the kana デ and ズ next to each other.

All together, the thing reads 「スサナ　エルナンデズ」. This looks like an attempted transcription of the name "Susanna Hernandez" into katakana.

I suspect the person who wrote it is relatively new to the language - the ン looks like a ソ, and assuming that "Susanna" is pronounced as it is in English, the first name should be スザナ, possibly with some long vowels thrown in.